# Represent in linear programming equations

Tags: linear-programming, binary-programming

If $B=1$, $A=0$

If $B=0$, $A$ can be 1 or 0.

Both $A$ and $B$ are binary variables.

How to represent these in linear programming equations?

Comment: You can go through this, this link is good. http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/LPBasics.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let $$B \le 1-A$$

If $B=1$, $1-A$ is forced to take value $1$.

Comment: You can derive this via conjunctive normal form:$$B\implies \neg A\\ \neg B \lor \neg A\\ (1-B)+(1-A)\ge 1\\ A+B\le 1$$

Comment: Can you pls explain line 2 and 3?

Comment: In logic, we know that $B \implies C$ is equivalent to $\neg B \lor C$. In our case $C$ corresponds to $\neg A$.  Negation of $B$ can be represented as $1-B$. For at least one of the indicator variable to be true, we want the sum to be at least $1$.

Comment: I do not know that $B⟹C$ is equivalent to ¬$B∨C$... thanks.